# jsf2 ajax update parts based on request parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf-2

this example is kind of extreme, and what im trying to do is not exactly this, but its more simple to demonstrate my problem with this

i have a page, with a simple index.xhtml:

```
<html
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:mc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mc">
    ...
    <h:panelGroup id="u1" styleClass="unique_container">
        <mc:component1></mc:component1>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="u2" styleClass="unique_container">
        <mc:component2></mc:component2>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="u3" styleClass="unique_container">
        <mc:component3></mc:component3>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <form action="/faces/async.xhtml">
        <input type="checkbox" name="renderu1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="renderu2" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="renderu1" />
        <input type="submit" value="render" />
    </form>
    ...
</html>
```

when i press on the "GO" button, i want to render component1 if renderu1 is checked, component2 if renderu2 is cheked, and component3 if renderu3 is checked

my current sollution for this is a js function using jQuery forms plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    registerForms($(document));
});

function registerForms(rootElement)
{
    rootElement.find("form").submit(function() {
    // submit the form
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(data, textStatus) {
        if(textStatus == "notmodified")
            return;


        var tempDiv = $('<div></div>');
        tempDiv.css("display", "none");
        tempDiv.html(data);
        var newUniqueContainer;
        while((newUniqueContainer = tempDiv.find(".unique_container:first")).html() != null)
        {
            var oldUniqueContainer = $("#" + newUniqueContainer.attr("id") + ":first");
            oldUniqueContainer.empty();
            oldUniqueContainer.html(newUniqueContainer.html());
            registerForms(oldUniqueContainer);
            newUniqueContainer.remove();
        }
        tempDiv.remove();
    });
    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation
    return false;
    });
}
```

what it does is whenever i submit a form, it fires an ajax request to the given url, waits for the response, and if theres content (status code is not 304, so its not "notmodified"), it gets the data, and replaces the content within the original "unique_containers" to the new data

async.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns:mc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mc"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <c:if test="#{asyncBean.render1}">
        <h:panelGroup id="u1" styleClass="unique_container">
            <mc:component1></mc:component1>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{asyncBean.render2}">
        <h:panelGroup id="u2" styleClass="unique_container">
            <mc:component2></mc:component2>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{asyncBean.render3}">
        <h:panelGroup id="u3" styleClass="unique_container">
            <mc:component3></mc:component3>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </c:if>
</html>
```

AsyncBean.java:

```
@ManagedBean(name="asyncBean")
@RequestScoped
public class AsyncBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.renderu1}")
    private boolean render1;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.renderu2}")
    private boolean render2;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.renderu3}")
    private boolean render3;

    private boolean isRender1() {
        return render1;
    }

    private void setRender1(boolean render1) {
        this.render1 = render1;
    }

    private boolean isRender2() {
        return render2;
    }

    private void setRender2(boolean render2) {
        this.render2 = render2;
    }

    private boolean isRender3() {
        return render3;
    }

    private void setRender3(boolean render3) {
        this.render3 = render3;
    }
}
```

so, for exapmle if only the 3rd checkbox is checked, the response will be something like this:

```
<html>
    <span id="u3" class="unique_container">
        content of component3
    </span>
</html>
```

its working fine, and its simple and all, but then i started using RichFaces for one of my components - the problem is, that it uses jQuery's $(document).ready(fn) function, and when i reload the part with RichFaces, it breaks (its a tree component, and i cant open the nodes)

i have been looking for a working sollution that can do what mine does, but is better prepared for compatibility issues (technically, i want to decide what part to update based on the parameters, so when the original page is rendered, i dont know yet what to write to "execute" and "render" attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a pretty terrible solution. You can solve this with pure JSF 2.0 without the need for jQuery, JSTL and custom tags. You can use `<f:ajax>` to fire an ajax request and render partial components. You can render JSF components conditionally by their `rendered` attribute.

Here's a basic kickoff example, assuming that you're running a Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 capable container with a `/WEB-INF/web.xml` declared as per Servlet 3.0 spec (otherwise the `.contains()` won't work in EL and you have to write a custom EL function).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
>
    ...
    <h:panelGroup id="panels">
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.panels.contains('u1')}">
            panel one
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.panels.contains('u2')}">
            panel two
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.panels.contains('u3')}">
            panel three
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:form>
        <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.panels}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="u1" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="u2" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="u3" />
            <f:ajax render=":panels" />
        </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    </h:form>
    ...
</html>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<String> panels;

    public List<String> getPanels() {
        return panels;
    }

    public void setPanels(List<String> panels) {
        this.panels = panels;
    }

}
```

That's all.