# JSF 2 EL function with Tomcat 6.0.x and EL 2.2

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat6, facelets, el

There are important parts of my JSF 2.0 application:

**functions.taglib.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/JSF/Facelet">
    <namespace>http://marius/components</namespace>
    <function>
       <function-name>empty</function-name>
       <function-class>com.test.ui.function.JsfFunctions</function-class>
       <function-signature>java.util.Boolean empty(java.lang.Object)</function-signature>
    </function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

**JsfFunctions class**:

```
package com.test.ui.function.function;

public class JsfFunctions {

    public static boolean empty(Object obj) {
        return obj == null;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/META-INF/functions.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**XHTML file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
    xmlns:func="http://marius/components"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="rendered" default="#{true}" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

    <t:dataScroller id="#{cc.attrs.tableId}Scroller"
            for="#{cc.attrs.tableId}"
            rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered and !func:empty(cc.attrs.dataModel)}">
    ....
```

**I get this error**:

```
javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: #{cc.attrs.rendered and !cl:empty(cc.attrs.dataModel)}
    com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:171)
    com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:188)


com.sun.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered ":" at line 1, column 28.
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
```

When I disable EL 2.2 integration everything works OK. Does it mean that EL 2.2 doesn't work with custom EL functions?

Answer (score 0):

Look here,

```
xmlns:func="http://marius/components"

...

rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered and !cl:empty(cc.attrs.dataModel)}"
```

You declared it on XML namespace `func`, but you're calling it on `cl:` namespace. Either rename XML namespace to `cl` or change the `cl:` prefix to `func:`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, there are several other issues:

1. You declared a Facelets 1.x taglib. As you're already on JSF/Facelets 2.x, you should prefer a Facelets 2.x taglib declaration.
2. You used a Facelets 1.x specific context param `facelets.LIBRARIES` which only exist in JSF/Facelets 2.x for backwards compatibility. But it will be removed sooner or later. You should use `java.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES` instead.
3. Why don't you just use the EL standard `empty` keyword?

   ```
   rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered and not empty cc.attrs.dataModel}">
   ```

   The `empty` keyword will check if it is `null` and if it's an array or a collection also if it has a length/size of `0`.

   If you just want to check for `null`, you could also just do

   ```
   rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered and cc.attrs.dataModel != null}">
   ```

#### See also:

- [How to create a custom EL function to invoke a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I fixed XML namespace prefix and issues you mentioned as number 1 and 2. But this doesn't helped, I still receive the same error. Function empty I used as an example. Real function will be more complex.

Comment: Apparently it's conflicting with Tomcat's own EL 2.1. I've never used Maven, nor used GF EL on Tomcat. I don't know what Maven is doing, but if Tomcat loads own EL 2.1 API while EL 2.2 impl is present, it will break. If your sole purpose being able to pass method arguments in EL, then I recommend using JBoss EL instead. Then you don't need EL 2.2 API. Just EL 2.1 as default provided by Tomcat suffices. Get rid of EL 2.2 dependencies and add group `org.jboss.el`, artifact `jboss-el` version `2.0.0` to your pom and finally edit the context param value to be `org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl`.

Comment: Note that you've two context params for it, one for Mojarra JSF impl and other for MyFaces JSF impl. One of them is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason of the error. It seems as error was thrown because my function had name "empty". Probably it is a reserved keyword. Everything works after renaming function.

Comment: It is a reserved keyword, it's used for collection types and strings.