# JSF converter for f:param

Tags: jsf, el

I'm using dynamically created links:

```
          <h:link outcome="/page" value="#{name}">
            <f:param name="name" value="#{name}"/>
          </h:link>
```

I would like to attach custom converter for f:param to remove spaces from #{name} etc.
But there is no converter property in f:param.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `Converter` is intented to convert from submitted `String` request parameter values to complex objects and vice versa in input fields. However, the `<f:param>` is pure output only and it will always call `toString()` on the value. It doesn't support a `Converter`.

Your cleanest and best bet is to create a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174), so that you ultimately end up like:

```html
<f:param name="name" value="#{util:prettyUrl(name)}"/>
```

---

**Update**: the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has since version 1.4 (March 2013) a `<o:param>` component which extends the `<f:param>` with support for a fullworthy JSF converter, exactly like as you'd use in `<h:outputText converter>`.

```
<h:link outcome="/page" value="#{name}">
    <o:param name="name" value="#{name}" converter="somePrettyURLConverter" />
</h:link>
```

See also the [showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/param).

Comment: I had the same question and I am not really satisfied with such a solution. On the receiving site `f:viewParam` is used to retrieve the Object using a converter. So it would be straight forward to use a converter with `f:param` too. Since that logic is already implemented in the converter. Now that logic is also present in the view and if i change the param maybe from name to id I have to change the converter and the site. The custom el function would be a workaround, at least if the initial converter would also use it.

Comment: added the `o:param` tag to his omnifaces library and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

what if you do something like this?

```
<f:param name="name" value="#{name.replace(' ', '')}" />
```

Isn't this working?

Or you want for all < f:param ... ??

Regards

Comment: Actually, the conversion is more complex, so I need java function. For now I use managed bean functions `<f:param name="name" value="#{util.myfunction(name)}" />`

Comment: @mm1: I don't think you have another solution.. It doesn't make sense... what you want is to replace the return of #{name} when is accessed by <f:param ... and I don't think you'll ever do this only for this kind of parameter...