# Change OutputText color inside a rich:dataTable

Tags: jsf, datatable, richfaces

I'm new to jsf and I can't solve this issue. 
I have an OutputText inside a rich:dataTable. I want to change the color of this OutputText according to its value (these values are integer). For example, if value is >= 50 then color is red, else color is white.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easily done with css, for example:

```
...
<h:outputText styleClass="#{row.value gt 50 ? 'red' : 'white'}" value="#{row.value}"/>
...
```

where classes red and white are defined accordingly or directly with style attribute:

```
...
<h:outputText style="color : #{row.value gt 50 ? 'red' : 'white'};" value="#{row.value}"/>
...
```

and even simpler markup when color/class is calculated in Java:

```
...
<h:outputText styleClass="#{row.volumeTag}" value="#{row.value}"/>
...
```

or in a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function):

```
...
<h:outputText styleClass="#{my:categorize(row.value)}" value="#{row.value}"/>
...
```

Comment: That's ok if I have only 2 conditions, but I have 4 conditions and I'd like to keep the xhtml clean. I would prefer a bean method do this.

Comment: @argonargon added another option. Here it is somewhat questionable because you may want to avoid mixing colors with your business logic. Opting for business meaningful class name like 'urgent'/'low-volumne' etc could be better.

Comment: to me, the third option is better (I add colors to a propoerty file or class), but this way I have to add a method to the row, which is a "view" bean. The model of this view bean is taken from a web service, so I'd like to avoid it. The best would be to have this logic in the backing bean.

Comment: @argonargon Depending on which EL version you are using, you can implement the logic in a static method or service method resulting in `styleClass="#{my:getCategory(row.value)}"` or `styleClass="#{categorizer.evaluate(row.value)}"`

Comment: jsf 1.2 does not support that syntax :(

Comment: @argonargon In case of JSF 1.2 the first option is for you. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function