# How to trigger component refresh from javascript in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to update a PrimeFaces component from javascript so that it would be force to refresh?

I am making an ajax save call using this button in a dialog.
I have attached my custom javascript  on the oncomplete event.

```
<p:growl life="1500" id="showmessage"/>
<p:dialog id="addMemberDialog" widgetVar="addMemberDlg">
    <!-- More Code -->
    <p:commandButton value="Save"
        actionListener="#{memberManagedBean.save}"
        oncomplete="handleSaveNewMember(xhr, status, args)"
        update=":memberListForm:membersTable createupdateform "
        process="@form" />
</p:dialog>
```

..during save button, I am adding a message here to display it to the client using the growl component.

```
public void save(ActionEvent event) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
            "Successfuly Add user", "Successfuly Add user");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);

}
```

My problem is, how can I sequence the UI such that, i should hide the dialog first before the growl component could show the meesage?

```
function handleSaveNewMember(xhr, status, args) {
    addMemberDlg.hide();
    //update the growl after the dialog was hidden?
}
```

What's happening is that the growl component is displayed alongside the dialog at the same time.

Thanks.

Comment: You must be showing the dialog on a button click. Did you try update of growl from that button rather than from Save button in dialog ?

Answer (score 58):

You can use PrimeFaces' [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) for this.

```html
<p:remoteCommand name="updateGrowl" update="showmessage" />
```

which is to be invoked as

```html
<p:commandButton ... oncomplete="addMemberDlg.hide(); updateGrowl();" />
```

---

In *this particular case* there's however a simpler way. Set the `autoUpdate` attribute of `<p:growl>` to `true`.

```html
<p:growl autoUpdate="true" life="1500" id="showmessage"/>
```

It'll auto-update itself on every ajax request. If your component actually didn't support it, then you could always wrap it in a `<p:outputPanel>` which also supports that attribute.

```html
<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
    ...
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Just a FYI if the reader is using a Jurassic version of PF, growl's autoupdate is only available from 3.0 and above. http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1164

Comment: And the `autoUpdate="..."` attribute is deprecated during the 6.2 elite release in favour of the `<p:autoUpdate>` tag/element which will be in the next community release as well. https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide

Answer (score 5):

you can always do something like this (remove the showmessage id from your save button update attribute)

```
<h:commandButton style="display:none" id="myBtn" >
    <f:ajax render=":showmessage"/>
</h:commandButton>

function handleSaveNewMember(xhr, status, args) {
    ...
    jQuery("#myBtn").click();
}
```

**EDIT**
But anyway in your current code , isn't the dialog being closed at the same time that the grwol being updated ?

Comment: Do you mean a 'dummy' button is needed for this and this cannot be accomplished thru some javascript api?  If this is the case, I was wondering that I should just follow this link http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18190&view=previous.  Since everything is ajaxified then I should trigger the messages from the client side itself.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: but in your case you want to send message from server , not from js... about my approach... I guess there other ways... but this is how i trigger "re render" of jsf element from js:)

Comment: oh you are right.  I have remove the showmessage from the update list since this would automatically show the facesmessage.  Let me try to explain further, on click of the save button, I have queued the facesmessage.  Since the autoupdate of the growl is false, the message won't show up.  That's the purpose of the oncomplete javascript function.  What happens is that I would hide first the dialog, then I would like the growl to refresh and display my queued message.  Is this possible?

Comment: the only way i could think atm is the way i proposed...   But anyway in your current code , isn't the dialog being closed at the same time that the grwol being updated ?

Answer (score 3):

My advice:

1. Use `<p:remoteCommand>` with an `actionListener` attribute. This attribute invokes a backing bean method that contains `FacesContext.addMessage` code, this way: `<p:remoteCommand actionListener="myBean.testMethod()" />`
2. Next, in your `handleSaveNewMember` script, invoke the `remoteCommand` `name` attribute after `addMemberDlg.hide();` this way: `<p:remoteCommand name="testScript" actionListener="myBean.testMethod()"/>`. Then, `function handleSaveNewMember(xhr, status, args) { addMemberDlg.hide(); testScript(); }`
3. Add `update` attribute to `remoteCommand` pointing growl component: `<p:remoteCommand name="testScript" actionListener="myBean.testMethod()" update="showmessage" />`
4. Your `commandButton` is OK.

This worked for me.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

PrimeFaces has an [Ajax API](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/core/ajaxJavascriptApi). You can use `PrimeFaces.ajax.Request.handle(cfg)`, or the shorter version `PrimeFaces.ab(cfg)` to trigger an update by using the `update` propery of the config object.

You probably want to set the `process` propery to your needs. If you don't need anything to be processed set it to `@none`.

Then, you are required to set the `source` property. You can set it to the current component using EL: `#{component.clientId}`.

Putting this all together you get:

```js
PrimeFaces.ab({source:'#{component.clientId}',process:'@none',update:'clientIdToUpdate'})
```

I created a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function-to-invoke-a-static-method) to reduce this to `#{my:ajaxUpdate('clientIdToUpdate')}`:

```java
public static String ajaxUpdate(final String clientIds) {
  return "PrimeFaces.ab({source:'"
                 + UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(Faces.getContext()).getClientId()
                 + "',process:'@none',update:'"
                 + clientIds
                 + "'})";
}
```

This reduces (for example):

```html
<p:remoteCommand name="updateMyComponent" update="myComponent"/>
...
<p:ajax event="filter" oncomplete="updateMyComponent()"/>
```

to:

```html
<p:ajax event="filter" oncomplete="#{my:ajaxUpdate('myComponent')}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you put p:Dialog inside of < h:panelGroup >. like

```
< h:panelGroup id="addUser" rendered = "boolean value " >
    < p:dialog id="addMemberDialog" widgetVar="addMemberDlg" >
        <!-- More Code -->
        < p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{memberManagedBean.createOrUpdate}"
                oncomplete="handleSaveNewMember(xhr, status, args)"
                update=":memberListForm:membersTable createupdateform :showmessage :addUser"
                process="@form" />
    < /p:dialog >
< /h:panelGroup>
```

boolean value which should be set in your save method. on setting this as false in your save method it wont display while updating it. So growl message alone will display. But before calling this save method this boolean value set as true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an PrimeFaces element called  p: remotecommand. This element will execute an action (to call a bean method, for example) and to execute an update after that action.

There is an example in this post http://devdublog.blogspot.com/2015/04/best-way-for-calling-method-of.html.

Comment: Answers should generally contain some context, not just a link.  This would be better suited as a comment to the question.  See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited the comment to fulfill this feature.