# How to execute one method of a backed bean in regular intervals

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an inputText area and the value attribute of the inputTextArea changes from time to time.How Can I call the METHOD on REGULAR INTERVALS so that the VALUE associated that component is always the latest.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632830/how-to-trigger-component-refresh-from-javascript-in-primefaces and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228198/jsf-refresh-periodically-a-component-with-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pollStartStop.jsf) will be the best bet for you.

```
 <h:inputTextarea id="autoUpdate" value="#{...}" />  
 <p:poll interval="4" listener="#{...}"  update="autoUpdate" autoStart="true"/>
```

Primefaces vdl description:

> Poll is an ajax component that has the ability to send periodical ajax
>   requests and execute listeners on JSF backing beans