# How to programmatically ajax-update specific component in backing bean

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, updates

Is there a way to ajax-update a specific component such as a `<h:form>` in backing bean?

I tried the following using [`RequestContext#execute()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29),

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.execute("monitorVehicleForm.update()");
```

however that didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: What's a "form" or "data table"?

Comment: See this [Trigger Component refresh from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632830/how-to-trigger-component-refresh-from-javascript-in-primefaces)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `RequestContext#execute()` only executes arbitrary JavaScript code which is been passed-in as argument. It does not ajax-update the client representation of the components.

You need [`RequestContext#update()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#update%28java.lang.String%29) instead wherein you just pass the client ID of the to-be-updated component.

```
context.update("monitorVehicleForm");
```

This has exactly the same effect as `<p:commandXxx ... update="monitorVehicleForm">`. This works provided you've a

```html
<h:form id="monitorVehicleForm">
```

without any [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) parent and thus have a

```html
<form id="monitorVehicleForm" name="monitorVehicleForm" ...>
```

in the generated HTML.

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762)