# RequestContext sends response but the page doesn't change

Tags: jsf, primefaces, requestcontext

I have a JSF page, with some components rendered if a certain value is selected in SelectOneMenu. For that I change their `rendered` value and call `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("@form")`.

From the client point of view, whenever I select the value, I get a response from server:

```
<update id="mainForm:addUser:menu_14:menu">
<...some updated values...>
</update>
```

Yet, the element with id `mainForm:addUser:menu_14:menu` did not update.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

**Update**
I can add commandButton with `update="@form"`, and pressing this button actually redraws the form as needed. But I need to do this from the backing bean, so...

Comment: Usually it's easier to do these things from the Facelets page, not the backing bean. I haven't encountered an instance where I "need" to update from the backing bean.

Comment: @DavidS: I have... But those are cases where a kind of framework is being developed

Comment: @DavidS: It's exactly the case -- we have a framework that creates JSF pages from XML file, so I don't have an access to the page source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> public abstract void update(String name)
>
> Update a component with ajax.
>
> name - Client side identifier of the component.

So you can't use selectors like you do from the `xhtml` file, you have to give client ID of the component.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("mainForm")
```

- [How to programmatically ajax-update specific component in backing bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101392/how-to-programmatically-ajax-update-specific-component-in-backing-bean)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Primefaces`? You should pass client id to `RequestContext.update` method. `@form` won't work. Try `update(mainForm)`.