# How to render a custom attribute of <h:outputLink>?

Tags: jsf, facelets, pinterest

I am trying to implement pinterest's pinit button using a snippet like the one below:

```
<h:outputLink value="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">
   <f:param name="url" value="#{beanOne.someMethod}/sometext{prettyContext.requestURL.toURL()}"/>
   <f:param name="media" value="#{beanOne.someOtherMethod}/sometext/somemoretext/#{beanTwo.someMethodTwo}-some-text.jpg"/>
   <f:param name="description" value="#{beanTwo.someOtherMethodTwo}"/>
   <img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
</h:outputLink>
```

Here are the gotcha's:

- the whole markup is created from the combination of four different methods from two different beans as well as some static text
- the url parameters obviously need to be urlencoded, therefore I am using f:param inside h:outputLink so that they get urlencoded
- the generated `a` tag needs to have the non-standard `count-layout="horizontal"` attribute

**Now my question is either one of:**

- How can I inject the count-layout attribute into h:outputLink or the generated anchor tag
- Otherwise if I cannot, what would be another non-invasive (I don't want to change the bean methods) way to accomplish the required pinit button markup?

The required markup can be found at http://pinterest.com/about/goodies/ down in the "pin it button for websites" section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use a normal `<a>` element along with a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function) which delegates to [`URLEncoder#encode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
<c:set var="url" value="#{beanOne.someMethod}/sometext#{prettyContext.requestURL.toURL()}"/>
<c:set var="media" value="#{beanOne.someOtherMethod}/sometext/somemoretext/#{beanTwo.someMethodTwo}-some-text.jpg"/>
<c:set var="description" value="#{beanTwo.someOtherMethodTwo}"/>

<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=#{utils:encodeURL(url)}&amp;media=#{utils:encodeURL(media)}&amp;description=#{utils:encodeURL(description)}" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">
   <img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
</a>
```

*(note that the `class` attribute was invalid for `<h:outputLink>`, you should be using `styleClass`)*

Or create a custom renderer for `<h:outputLink>` which adds support for `count-layout` attribute. Assuming that you're using Mojarra, simplest would be to extend its `OutputLinkRenderer`:

```
public class ExtendedLinkRenderer extends OutputLinkRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void writeCommonLinkAttributes(ResponseWriter writer, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        super.writeCommonLinkAttributes(writer, component);
        writer.writeAttribute("count-layout", component.getAttributes().get("count-layout"), null);
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Link</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.ExtendedLinkRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Comment: the custom renderer looks like a much cleaner way and allows space for future requirements. thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you're this way JSF implementation dependent. If you ever switch to MyFaces, you'd have to change this. You could also create an independent renderer instead, but that would require lot of non-DRY boilerplate code.