# Display exception stack trace into Facelets page

Tags: java, jsf, exception, jsf-2, facelets

I need to display exception stack trace into my JSF application `error.xhtml` page. I know how simple is to do it with JSP page. But with JSF 2.0 I have a problem.

In my `web.xml` I have defined a JSF 2.0 Facelets page as error page:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/faces/views/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

When the error occurs the I get redirected to this page. What I need is to display the stack trace of exception in this Facelets page.

I have tried to use:

```
<pre>
    <h:outputText value="${exception}"/>
</pre>
```

But I don't get any output. I have been searching the internet but I did not find a solution. How can I display the exception stack trace in the Facelets page?

**EDIT:**

I have just tried:

```
<c:forEach var="exeption" items="${exception.stackTrace}">
    <div>${exeption}</div>
</c:forEach>

<h:dataTable value="#{exception.stackTrace}"
             var="exception">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{exception}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

JSTL not working and interating through datatable also not working. I am sure that exception occurs, I see it in my log files.

Comment: Did you try to iterate over the Stack Trace elements? Like using a for with itens are ${exception.stackTrace}?

Comment: No, I did not try that. I will try it now and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! I will post an answer if it works ;)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working, I have edited the question.

Comment: I pretty rusty with JSF, but maybe <h:outputText/> only accepts Strings (I really don't remember). Try something like `#{exception.message}` to see if something is generated.

Comment: No, I have also tried this, no success :(

Comment: Do you perhaps need to pull it from the request scope as in `${requestScope.exception.message}`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's present as a request attribute with the name as specified by the [`RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#ERROR_EXCEPTION) constant.

```
#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception']}
```

This gives you the whole `Exception` object. Getting its stacktrace requires a bit more work. You basically need to [create a custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174) which does basically something like this:

```
public static String printStackTrace(Throwable exception) {
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stringWriter, true));
    return stringWriter.toString();
}
```

so that you can use it as follows:

```html
<pre>#{my:printStackTrace(requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception'])}</pre>
```

The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) offers this as well. See also the [`FullAjaxExceptionHandler` showcase page](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler).

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. Now I can see the exception, I will write el function get the full stack trace. Thanks again :)