# Handling jspx templates

Tags: java, servlets, jspx

I'm doing my first steps in jspx. I really like the xml-Syntax. Feels much more familiar than jsp and it forces me to undo my dirty hacks that jsp forgives. One of that hacks is this:

```
<img src="<b:Resource name="myImage.png" />" alt="some text" title="even more text" />
```

**How to do it right in jspx?**

**My first thought:** Write your own tag, but I really don't want to rewrite all the html-elements that could need an resource-reference with all of its possible attributes. Or is there maybe an existing library with those html-elements which I could extend to support my needed functionality?

**Another idea:** Doing something like:

```
<b:Resource name="myImage.png" var="imgVar"/>
<img src="${imgVar}" alt="some text" title="even more text" />
```

But I have to thing about my web developer agencies. They dont feel really happy with jsp. If I start using syntax like this, they'll totally quit.

Is there a good solution.

B.t.w.
Using `&#160;` instead of `&nbsp;` is disliked by some of my web developers, too. **Is there a better way in jspx?**

Answer (score 0):

you might consider writing a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function), so you could use:

```
<img src="${b:resource('myImage.png')}"
     alt="some text"
     title="even more text" />
```