# JSF EL - replace null with default value

Tags: jsf, null, el

Is there a way to replace null with a default value in JSF EL expressions, sort of like the Oracle `NVL` function?

I know I can do something like

```
#{obj == null ? 'None' : obj.property}
```

But was hoping there is an automatic way to do it so I'm not copy/pasting the same expression on both sides of the ternary Elvis operator.

I'm looking for something like

```
#{default(obj.property, 'None')}
```

Comment: What version of jsf/el as if you are on a new version you can define el functions

Comment: @Stephen: EL functions are always been supported since EL 1.0 and is independent from JSF version.

Comment: Thanks good to know... Perhaps it is defining them that was tricky until el 2.2

Comment: @Stephen: that part was never changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No such thing exist in EL. Not [now](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html) and not in the [future](http://java.net/projects/el-spec/pages/Operators).

Your best bet is creating a custom EL function.

```
#{my:def(obj.property, 'None')}
```

*(note: as `default` is a Java keyword/literal, it's invalid to use exactly this name as function name in EL)*

If you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), then you can use [`#{of:coalesce()}`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Objects) for the exact purpose.

#### See also:

- [How to create a custom EL function to invoke a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174)

Answer (score 2):

In some situations you can use this:

```
<c:out value="${obj.property}" default="None"/>
```

(as suggested [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/643867/JSP/java/print-null-values-EL#2959730))

Comment: OP is using Facelets, not JSP.

Comment: I did say "in some situations". Also, this is the only question about "replace null with default value in EL" (thet the search provides), so it is what people will find when searching for an answer (related to JSF,JSP or in general).