# Output int as hexadecimal in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

Before I write a custom tag to do this, I want to be sure I didn't miss something in EL or JSTL.

There's an int returned by a bean property that is stored in the request scope.  I need to output it as hex.  But after searching, it seems there is no way in JSP to output an int that is returned from a bean by EL thusly...

```
${someBean.someInt}
```

...as a hexadecimal value, in the way that...

```
<%= String.format("0x%X", someBean.getSomeInt()) %>
```

...would.

Am I correct?  If not, how is it done?  (Our departmental coding standards disallow Java directly included in JSP using the `<% %>` syntax.  We have to write tags if we can't find something already available.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in EL or using JSTL's formatting tags. Writing a custom tag or [EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function) is the best option.

If it's just one `int` you have to format you could add a String getter to your bean to do the formatting

```
public String getSomeIntAsHex(){
  return String.format("0x%X", someInt);
}
```

and then you could use that getter in EL

```
${someBean.someIntAsHex}
```

Comment: I used your second suggestion.  But I'm curious about the EL Function approach.  How do I output text to the page from within an EL Function?  Or is the return value of the function automatically output to the page?

Comment: Something like `${myTagLib:intToHex(someBean.someInt)}` which you could directly output or use in `<c:out value=""/>`.