# How do i set end value and begin value dynamically in c:forEach loop?

Tags: jsf, facelets, icefaces, mojarra

Good afternoon.

I have the following problem, the end of the attribute value

```
<c: foreach should vary for each row in the datatable, eh trying with expression language but simply does not work.
```

This is the code:

```
<ace:dataTable  value="#{TreeTableBk.rubros}" var="rubro"
                paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="10" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif">
                <ace:column
                    headerText="Informacion">
                    <div align="left">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <c:forEach begin="0" end="#{rubro.nivel}">
                            <h:outputText value="__*"></h:outputText>
                        </c:forEach>
                        <h:inputText 
                        value      = "#{rubro.codigoPadre}"
                        rendered   = "#{rubro.final_ == 'N'}"
                        styleClass = "SMRInputTextNegrilla6" 
                        style      = "background-color:#A5CCE7">
                        </h:inputText>
                    <h:inputText 
                        value      = "#{rubro.codigoPadre}"
                        rendered   = "#{rubro.final_ == 'S'}"
                        styleClass = "SMRInputTextNegrilla6" >
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:inputText 
                        value      = "#{rubro.codigo}"
                        styleClass = "SMRInputTextNegrilla6" 
                        style      = "background-color:#D1F2C7">
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:inputText 
                        value      = "#{rubro.descripcion}"
                        styleClass = "SMRInputTextNegrilla6" >
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:inputText value="#{rubro.nivel}" styleClass="SMRInputTextNegrilla6">
                    </h:inputText>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    </div>
                </ace:column>
            </ace:dataTable>
```

Any idea how to resolve this would be helpful.

many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag handlers like `<c:forEach>` runs during building the view, not during rendering the view. UI components like `<h:dataTable>` runs during rendering the view, not during building the view. So, at the moment the `<c:forEach>` runs, the `<h:dataTable>` isn't running and thus its `var="rubro"` is never available in the EL scope and thus `#{rubro}` inside `<c:forEach>` *always* evaluates as `null`.

So, the `<c:forEach>` is completely out of the question for this particular functional requirement. Your best bet is using the `<ui:repeat>`. This does however not support anything like the `begin` and `end` attribute of the `<c:forEach>`. You could however create a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174) which creates a dummy array of the given size and then feed it to `<ui:repeat value>`.

E.g.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{my:createArray(robro.nivel)}">
    <h:outputText value="__*" />
</ui:repeat>
```

with

```
public static Object[] createArray(int size) {
    return new Object[size];
}
```

The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has an `of:createArray()` function for exactly this purpose, see also [the `of:createArray()` showcase example](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Arrays).

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)
- [How to create a custom EL function to invoke a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174)

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the solution to the problem. Blessings and good luck