# Expression Language: how to simplify this statement ("in"-like clause needed)

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, el, in-clause

If would be great if I could replace

```
${myvar eq 'foo' or myvar eq 'bar' or myvar eq 'john' or myvar eq 'doe' or myvar eq ...}
```

by either

```
${myvar in ['foo', 'bar', 'john', 'doe', ...]}
```

or

```
${myvar in {'foo', 'bar', 'john', 'doe', ...}}
```

but none of them worked. Any alternative solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create an EL function for that. A kickoff example for Facelets can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174) and another one for JSP can be found somewhere near the bottom of [our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

```
public static boolean contains(Object[] array, Object item) {
    if (array == null || item == null) {
        return false;
    }

    for (Object object : array) {
        if (object != null && object.toString().equals(item.toString())) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

*(or if you're using JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), use its [`of:contains()`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Arrays), although it works in Facelets only, not in the deprecated JSP)*

then use it as follows:

```html
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@taglib prefix="my" uri="http://my.example.com/functions" %>
...
${my:contains(fn:split('foo,bar,john,doe', ','), myvar)}
```

*(the `fn:split()` is merely a trick to convert a delimited `String` to a `String[]`)*

You could even simplify/specialize it further by passing the delimited string directly and perform the split in the function so that you can end up like as:

```html
${my:contains('foo,bar,john,doe', myvar)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a variable `mylist` with the list of names and use `contains`:

```
mylist.contains(myvar)
```