# Dynamic javascript in jsf application

Tags: javascript, jsf, myfaces

It's possible to include javascript via outputScript tag from jsp which generate is? (contentType=application/javascript)

Or maybe there is another way to achieve localized javascript in facelets (best practice)?

Comment: my question is about how to do this by outputScript tag in myfaces, given: jsf which generates javascript like in replies from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575128/passing-localized-javascript-messages-from-ressource-bundles-using-jsf goal: output it by myfaces outputScript tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<h:outputScript>` doesn't support JSP/Facelets files, but only real plain `.js` files.

Your best bet is using "plain vanilla" `<script>` element.

```
<script src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/script.jsp"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, it's possible to include it inside head from some composition define tag?

Comment: Certainly. Just put a `<ui:insert name="head" />` in the desired location of `<h:head>` of master template and then declare the above script inside `<ui:define name="head">` of template client.