# Recognize links in h:outputText

Tags: html, jsf, hyperlink

I need to show some text using `<h:outputText>` tag component. There is this requirement that if the text contains an URLs i.e. `http//example.com.co`, I need show it as a link.

For example, if user enters *Yo quiero www.google.com* I need to show *Yo quiero [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)*

Comment: You are taking input from the User or you have some predefined value in a text and you want to output that to the User ?

Comment: Hi, input from the User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function which does a regular expression replace on your string. You can use `string.replaceAll()` for this.

You have multiple options to place this function.

1. You can create a method in your backing bean.
2. You can create a custom jsf tag ([example](http://jdevelopment.nl/simple-java-based-jsf-custom-component/))
3. You can create a custom el function ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080174/1107109))

No 1 is the easiest to implement imho.

Comment: Hi, I try with the 1. But, I have this <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>. The  <h:outputText> tag component show <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a> and not one link. I need use another tag component? Thanks.