# Interpreting a posted url as a hyperlink in primefaces

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am developing an application using Primefaces 5, and part of the app allows users to post information for example a user posting this >>> "please kim visit www.primefaces.org and reading abt primefaces there". The issues is l want the url to be displyed as a hyperlink when the post is being seen by other users. The bold part in the code below is showing the posted message.

```
   <div id="postcontent_div"> 
       <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="background-color: #fff;padding-top: 0px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff"> 
           <p:commandLink styleClass="profilenamelink" ajax="false" value="#{post.username} "/> 
           <h:outputText value="How to master Algorithms" style="font-size: 12px;font-weight:bold;color:black"/> 
       </h:panelGrid> 
       <h:outputText value="#{post.message}" style="font-size: 12px"/> 
  </div>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

With primefaces `<p:link>`. 
See documentation : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/link.xhtml

With default JSF implementation `<h:outputLink>`
See documentation : http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_outputLink.html

**EDIT :**

If you want to parse URL from a String, there are a few methods available. See similar answer : [Recognize links in h:outputText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698752/recognize-links-in-houtputtext)

Comment: Thank you @Thrax for a quick reply. From the question the user is posting a message with a url inside like "please kim visit www.primefaces.org and reading about primefaces". When displaying the message using <p:outputtext value=""/> the url www.primefaces.org url should be interpreted as a hyperlink automatically but its not happening. how can l go about it?.