# JSF Selectitems Format Label Number

Tags: jsf, converters, selectonemenu

I've got a List of Numbers (range 500 - 5000, steps of 500).
I would like to add a decimal dot 1000 -> 1.000; 2500 -> 2.500 etc. but just for the labels not to be saved as a value.
I tried the following but it didnt work:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedValue}">
    <f:convertNumber type="currency" locale="de-DE" pattern="#,###" />
    <f:selectItems itemValue="#{bean.selectItemslist}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.label}" itemValue="#{item.value} />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

But this didnt do anything :(

Tried several patterns and included integerOnly="true" but nothing seems to work :(
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The converter applies on the item value only, not on the item label. That explains why it "fails". In this particular case, your best bet is to create a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174), so that you end up something like this:

```
<f:selectItems ... itemLabel="#{my:formatNumber(item.label, '#,###')}" />
```

The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has several, see also [OmniFaces *functions/Numbers* showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Numbers).