# How to escape/avoid the ampersand (&) in a JSF url

Tags: jsf, url, special-characters, html-escape-characters

I use `window.open(url,"selectWindow","status=no,width=610,height=480,scrollbars=no")` in JSF.
The url looks something like this :

```
/abcxyz.jsf?param1=value1&amp;param2=value2
```

which would show in the popup window like :

```
/abcxyz.jsf?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

The problem is, the `value2` is a string which has an `&` in it. Say, `value2 = ab&12`. How can I make sure that the `value2` is read as `ab&12` and that it doesn't break after `ab` because of the `&` symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [URL-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it. In plain Java, that would be

```
String encodedValue2 = URLEncoder.encode(value2, "UTF-8");
```

The `&` should this way become `%26`. The charset should be the same as the server is been configured to use to decode the incoming HTTP request URI (which often defaults to ISO-8859-1 though).

The JSF [`<f:param>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/param.html) also does that when used in [`<h:outputLink>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputLink.html) and [`<h:link>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html), however they aren't helpful in generating URLs for `window.open()`, so you'd really need to perform this in backing bean with help of `URLEncoder` or create a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174). If you happen to use the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), then you could use [`#{of:encodeURL()}`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Strings) for that.

#### See also:

- [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding)