# How do I show display the class of a map in Expression Language (EL)?

Tags: jsp, el

If I have some object stored as a request attribute named myObject I can find out its type in JSP EL like this:

`${myObject['class']}`

But if I have a `java.util.Map` stored as a request attribute myMap, and I put this in my page...

`${myMap['class']}`

...the Map is searched for an entry whose key is "class".  This makes sense, otherwise we could never retrieve anything in EL from a Map with a key of "class".

So how do I display the type of my Map in an EL statement?

(And most of you will want to ask me: "Why do you care?".  Well, today I was working on a train with no Internet connection and I had to iterate a `java.util.HashMap` in a page, and I completely forgot how to do that.  So, not being able to Google or SO it, I decided to find out what the type was (I knew it wasn't an actual java.util.HashMap, Tomcat turns it into something else) so I could go rummaging around in the Tomcat jar files and see what methods it exposed and maybe figure it out myself.  Well, I couldn't find out the type via EL.  I resorted to embedded Java inside `<%  %>` tags.  But it has been bothering me all day that I coulnd't find out with EL alone.  So, that's why I care.  It's eating me up.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) 2.2+ you can simply use:

```
${myMap.getClass()}
```

An other possiblity could be writing a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function) or tag. There you could check if the object is an instance of [`java.util.AbstractMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html).