# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when handling array on view

Tags: jsf, primefaces

actualy my question is how to display a collection in my view :
ex:

```
<h:outputText value="#{item.machineCollection.get(0).id != null ? item.machineCollection.get(0).id : ''}"/>
```

even after testing my code if the result is null i got this error

> Array index out of range: 0
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
>     at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:694)    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.get(IndirectList.java:401)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor194.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)   at
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:134)    at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)    at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstNotEqual.getValue(AstNotEqual.java:58)   at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstChoice.getValue(AstChoice.java:64)   at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstDeferredExpression.getValue(AstDeferredExpression.java:63)
>     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:68)
>     at
>   com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)   at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularCell(DataTableRenderer.java:741)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:693)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:601)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:220)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:192)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:74)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:43)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:198)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:115)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:55)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
>     at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:55)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:43)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

if someone have a solution urgently pleas and thanks

Comment: You want to print the list in the outputtext ? Why?

Comment: You simple have a empty list on your page. check your server side code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have

```
item.machineCollection.get(0).id
```

If you have an empty collection, `item.machineCollection.get(0)` will not work.

In primeface datatable you can use the `var` attribute. So if you add `var="row"` you can do

```
<p:datatable var="row" value="#{item.machineCollection}" >
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Id" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{row.id}"/>
    </p:column>
....
</p:datatable>
```

Comment: ok but, how to get it if not null and return nothing if null without error ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you wanted to do, but from your code and stack trace I'm guessing it's something similar to this. (I updated my answer)

Comment: @user1643422 if the list is empty (i.e. it has `null` value or it doesn't contain any item) then the `<p:dataTable>` won't display anything at all.

Comment: @user1643422 please use `@username` to answer a comment. The problem looks that your managed bean has a wrong scope, make sure it is at least `@ViewScoped`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **not empty** operator:

```
<h:outputText value="#{not empty item.machineCollection ? item.machineCollection.get(0).id : ''}
```

or write custom JSF function, as described in this topic:

[How to create a custom EL function to invoke a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function)

Comment: i tryed #{! empty item.machineCollection.get(0).libelle} but range 0 exception come back .. :s

Comment: `#{! empty item.machineCollection.get(0).libelle}`