# Pass Parameter to JSF backing bean while rendering of rich data table

Tags: tomcat6, jsf-1.2

i m using JSF 1.2, Servlets 2.5, Tomcat "6" and richfaces 3. I m displaying data from a table in oracle on page using rich:dataTable. now i need to display some customized information in a particular column of table row depending on its id. i tried to send parameter to my backing bean as follows (i know tomcat 7 and el 2.2 jar , servlets 3 would solve this prob but i cant move from my present setup so i wana know my alternatives. thanks)

```
    <rich:dataTable rendered="true" value="#{studentBean.studentList}" var="dataList">
      ...
   <rich:column sortable="true">
 <f:facet name="header">
  <h:outputText value="Details"/>
     </f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{studentBean.studentCategory(dataList.id)}"/>
   </rich:column>
      ...
    </rich:dataTable>
```

my backing bean is

```
public String studentCategory(Long id)
 {
        String categoryString;
        //...process table rows with id and return a 
        //...concatenated string
   return categoryString;
 }
```

I get following error

```
 The function studentCategory must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is   
 not specified
```

Help is solicited.

Answer (score 1):

JSF 1.2 doesn't support pass arguments to methods. Since you can't migrate to JSF 2. The solution can be use Facelets it lets you implement EL functions.

You can see this answer:

[How to create a custom EL function to invoke a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function)

And this article

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/j-facelets2/index.html