# c:forEach runs always the same amount of loops

Tags: jsf, jstl

hi i'm trying to display a tree structure in JSF

for intendation i want to insert

```
<span class="intendWidth" />
```

this is my jsf-code

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myHandler.entityTree}" var="entityDepthHolder">
    <p:commandLink action="#{myHandler.toggle(entityDepthHolder.entity)}">
        <div>
            <c:forEach begin="0" end="#{entityDepthHolder.depth}">
                <span class="intendWidth" />
            </c:forEach>
            #{entityDepthHolder.depth} #{entityDepthHolder.entity.title}
        </div>
    </p:commandLink>
</ui:repeat>
```

but for some reason the c:forEach always run once, although only one entityDepthHolder.depth is 1, all others are 0

any ideas how to insert a tag n-times without c:forEach?

Comment: Since only one `entityDepthHolder.depth` is one, then the loop body will be applied only one time.

Comment: @kocko: you're wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<c:forEach>` runs during view build time (that moment when XHTML is turned into JSF component tree), while the `<ui:repeat>` runs during view render time (that moment when JSF component tree produces HTML output).

So, when the `<c:forEach>` runs, the `#{entityDepthHolder}` is nowhere available in the EL scope and evaluates to `null` and in this case implicitly coerced to `0`. As the `begin` is also `0` and the `end` is inclusive, you effectively end up with 1 item.

After the view build time, the JSF component tree ends up like this:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myHandler.entityTree}" var="entityDepthHolder">
    <p:commandLink action="#{myHandler.toggle(entityDepthHolder.entity)}">
        <div>
            <span class="intendWidth" />
            #{entityDepthHolder.depth} #{entityDepthHolder.entity.title}
        </div>
    </p:commandLink>
</ui:repeat>
```

And during view render time, the very same HTML is repeatedly generated.

You've 2 options to fix this:

1. Use `<c:forEach>` instead of `<ui:repeat>` on the outer loop. Caveat is, this breaks view scoped beans in Mojarra versions older than 2.1.18.
2. Use `<ui:repeat>` instead of `<c:forEach>` on the inner loop. If you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), then you may find the [`#{of:createArray()}`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Arrays) function helpful in this.

   ```
   <ui:repeat value="#{of:createArray(entityDepthHolder.depth)}">
   ```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: thanks.. so there isn't a build-in possibility to display a tag n-times?

Comment: Not with `<ui:repeat>` in its standard trim, no. I've ever [proposed](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1102) to JSF spec guys to add support for `begin` and `end`, however no work on that was done yet. Your best bet is `of:createArray()` (click the link in answer to see showcase example), or just to create a simliar one on your own, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/