# rendered tag on class types of css using jsf

Tags: css, jsf, render, el

I was wondering if there is a library out there which enables me to do something like the following:

```
<h:outputText value="blablabla">
    <x:styleClass value="class1" rendered="#{bean.firstboolean}"/>
    <x:styleClass value="class2" rendered="#{bean.secondboolean}"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Thus enabling the classes depending on whether the expression returns true during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that easily from your bean. In your `xhtml` use something like:

```
<h:outputText value="blablabla" styleClass="#{bean.styleClass}"/>
```

And in your bean:

```
public String getStyleClass(){
   return firstboolean ? "class1" : "class2";
}
```

---

**Update**: If you don't want this logic to be present in your bean you could have the logic in your `xhtml`:

```
<h:outputText value="blablabla"
              styleClass="#{bean.firstboolean ? 'class1' : 'class2'}"/>
```

It would be even better to write a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function) to create reusable logic, resulting in something like:

```
<h:outputText value="blablabla"
              styleClass="#{mylib:styleForObject(object)}"/>
```

Comment: Yea could be done like that, but would kinda break the MVC principle right? I am looking for a tag like this one and hoping someone knows a lirary providing something like this :)

Comment: If you want the logic in your `xhtml` you could use `styleClass="#{bean.firstboolean ? 'class1' : 'class2'}"`.

Comment: Or you could create a custom EL function for it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function

Comment: Thanks that was more or less what I wanted to have :)