# Adding day number ordinal suffixes like st, nd and th using f:convertDateTime

Tags: jsf, date, numbers, converters, ordinal

I would to add day number ordinal suffixs 26th, or 1st, or 2nd.

How can I do this in JSF using `<f:convertDateTime>`? I have tried using `pattern` attribute with `dd`, however this only prints the whole number without any ordinal suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't supported by [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) which is being used under the covers by [`<f:convertDateTime>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/convertDateTime.html).

You'd need to write a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174) for this. Such a function could look like this:

```
public static String getDayWithSuffix(Date date) {
    if (date == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int day = Integer.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("d").format(date));

    if (day / 10 == 1) {
        return day + "th";
    }

    switch (day % 10) {
        case 1: return day + "st";
        case 2: return day + "nd";
        case 3: return day + "rd";
        default: return day + "th";
    }
}
```

And be used like this:

```
#{my:getDayWithSuffix(bean.date)}
```

For remainder, like month of year, just use another output with `<f:convertDateTime>` the usual way.