# Printing unlocalized number in JSTL

Tags: jstl

I have a page which will be available in several locales and would like to store a number in a hidden field for the purpose of calculations, for example:

I want to have the value 7.00 in there no matter what the locale is. If I go the route of using (I'm using spring to populate the view and would prefer not having to change anything on what is passed to the view):

```
<fmt:formatNumber var="somenumberineed1" value="${somenumberigot1}" minFractionDigits="2" />
<input type="hidden" id="somenumberineed1" value="${somenumberineed1}">
```

I'll end up with this for some European countries:

```
<input type="hidden" id="somenumberineed1" value="7,00">
```

Is there some way to just print the number with a set minimum fractional digits using jstl? I'd preferably not like to mess around with the set locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function) which manually formats the float using [`java.text.DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) with custom [`java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) (or just create a `DecimalFormatSymbols` instance using [`Locale.US`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US)).