# Using a method as a function in a JSF page

Tags: jsf

Below you can see a method that return an IP address.

I'd like to use it in a JSF page. How can I achieve this?

```
public static String getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request) {  
  HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
  String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
  if (ipAddress == null) {
      ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
  }
  return ipAddress;
}
```

Comment: There is no best way. Me: I'd just return it through a JSF managed bean property that calls the utility function.

Comment: please supply your jsf page

Comment: It's a pretty simple program. Actually, it is a contact form. I'd like to catch IP address to show it and write on database together the others fields.

Comment: What the `HttpServletRequest request` parameter is supposed to do in your method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a custom EL function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function)

Comment: By the way, the `X-Forwarded-For` header contains multiple IP addresses commaseparated ... If you're using OmniFaces, better use `Faces#getRemoteAddr()`. That `HttpServletRequest` argument which you never use locally (and is causing uncompilable code) is also weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you have to do is work with request to show the IP in the view, you don't even need to call a method from a managed bean, you can do it directly in your Facelet:

```
<p>
    IP of request: #{empty header['X-FORWARDED-FOR'] ? request.remoteAddr : header['X-FORWARDED-FOR']}
</p>
```

Comment: nice solution. clean, elegante and it works. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your java function have doublicate variable names.
Look at the function parameter (request) and at the local variable name request.

Remove the function parameter, cos you get it from facesContext.

you can access the result by a direct function call from the view like :

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.getClientIpAddr()}" />
```

Comment: Note that you'd need to make `getClientIpAddr` non-static for this to work.

Answer (score -1):

What about this:
"#{request.getHeader('X-FORWARDED-FOR') != null ? request.getHeader('X-FORWARDED-FOR') : request.remoteAddr}"

Comment: You're missing the else part of the ternary.

Comment: Then you'll obtain the complete header?