# How can I split a String in Expression Language and take the last element?

Tags: java, string, jsp, split, el

This is what I am trying but it seems not to work:

```
(myStringHere.split(".")[(myStringHere.split(".").length)-1]).concat(text[myStringHere])
```

The string I have will be something like this:

```
com.foo.bar.zar.gar.ThePartIWant
```

ThePartIWant is what I want to show in the page only.

I am using Expression Language 2.2

Comment: How can you get value from text array using String as a index value?

Comment: @SurendarKannan I am not using String as a index value?

Comment: Then this means text[myStringHere]?

Comment: text[] is a function I am calling, it is really not important for the question.

Comment: Fine if it's a function, it will be like this text(myStringHere)..

Comment: @SurendarKannan There is nothing wrong with that part. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function Find on this page: Finally you can use it as intended: I do not know why you are so obssessed about that part of the question, it is not even relavent?

Comment: EL was introduced to clean up JSP pages and avoid scriptlets (so that programming logic is moved out of the JSPs). IMHO its better to implement this logic in the server-side. Any constraint on implementing the logic on server-side and returning the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are doing it in JSP then try with [JSP JSTL function tag library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalg.html) that provide lost of methods as defined here in [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html)

Read more here on [Oacle The Java EE 5 Tutorial - JSTL Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnalg/index.html)

Here is the code to get the last value based on split on dot.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
 ...

<c:set var="string1" value="This.is.first.String." />
<c:set var="string2" value="${fn:split(string1, '.')}" />

<c:set var="lastString" value="${string2[fn:length(string2)-1]}" />

<c:out value="${lastString }"></c:out>
```

output:

```
String
```

---

Here is one more [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_split.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You want to catch only the last part of your string ? Try this :

```
string[] s_tab = myStringHere.split(".");
string result = s_tab[s_tab.length - 1];
```

If you want it in one line :

```
string result = myStringHere.split(".")[StringUtils.countMatches(myStringHere, ".")];
```

Comment: I am using Expression Language and I need to get this done in one line.

Comment: `string result = myStringHere.split(".")[myStringHere.split(".").length - 1];` doesn't work ?!

Comment: No, does not work: javax.el.ELException: /test/test.xhtml: For input string: "length"

Comment: Maybe if you cast it `string result = myStringHere.split(".")[((string[])myStringHere.split(".")).length - 1];` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String s = "com.foo.bar.zar.gar.ThePartIWant";
```

`System.out.println(s.split("\\.")[(s.split("\\.").length)-1]);`

"." is a special character. You have to escape it because period means any character in regex.

Source : [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Thanks but does not work: javax.el.ELException: /test/test.xhtml: For input string: "length"