# Why f:param value is not set into message from resource bundle?

Tags: jsf, internationalization, resourcebundle

I work with internationalization in my webapp and I want reuse some messages again.
**faces-config.xml**

```
<locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>uk</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>international.message-labels</base-name>
        <var>msgLabel</var>
    </resource-bundle>
```

**Message from resource bundle**

```
inputLength=Length should be {0} or more
```

**Example:**

```
<p:inputText id="firstName" value="#{user.firstName}"
                placeholder="#{msgLabel.namePlaceHolder}" size="25" required="true"
                styleClass="logRegLabel" validatorMessage="#{msgLabel.inputLength}"
                requiredMessage="#{msgLabel.fieldCannotEmpty}">
                <f:param value="3" />
                <f:validateLength minimum="3" />
                <p:ajax event="blur" update="firstNameMsg" global="false" />
            </p:inputText>
```

In all examples that I saw it works. But in my case I always got `Length should be {0} or more` instead of `Length should be 3 or more`
I tried this `validatorMessage="#{msgLabel['inputLength']}"` too
Also, I tried to delete all another parameters of `p:inputText` but it did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<f:param>` to parameterize bundle messages works inside `<h:outputFormat>` only.

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{bundle.key}">
    <f:param value="value for {0}" />
    <f:param value="value for {1}" />
    <f:param value="value for {2}" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

JSF doesn't offer any facility to parameterize an arbitrary attribute value. Your best bet would be creating a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function) which does the job like below:

```
<p:inputText ... validatorMessage="#{my:format1(msgLabel.inputLength, '3')}" />
```

If you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), then you can use its [`of:format1()`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Strings) for that.

```
<p:inputText ... validatorMessage="#{of:format1(msgLabel.inputLength, '3')}" />
```

Or its [`<o:outputFormat>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/outputFormat) which supports capturing the output in an EL variable.

```
<o:outputFormat value="#{msgLabel.inputLength}" var="validatorMessage">
    <f:param value="3" />
</o:outputFormat>
<p:inputText ... validatorMessage="#{validatorMessage}" />
```