# Format result of JSF EL arithmetic operation

Tags: jsf, el

The division of two integers is resulting in a floating point value.
Is there a way to get the result as an integer in the following situation?

```
<p:commandButton value="#{bean.intA / bean.intB}" ../>
```

The result should be shown as "1" not as "1.0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EL doesn't support upcasting/formatting. An universal solution would be to create a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function) referring the below utility method:

```
public static String formatNumber(Number number, String pattern) {
    if (number == null) {
        return null;
    }

    DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(getLocale());
    formatter.applyPattern(pattern);
    return formatter.format(number);
}
```

You can then use it as below:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{util:formatNumber(bean.intA / bean.intB, '#')}" ... />
```

In case you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), it's available as [`#{of:formatNumber()}`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Numbers) whose source code is actually copied above.