# Utility methods in application scoped bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, application-scope

Do you think it is a good idea to put all widely used utility methods in an application scoped bean?

In the current implementation of the application I'm working on, all utility methods (manipulating with Strings, cookies, checking url, checking current page where the user is etc.) are all put in one big request scoped bean and they are referenced from every xhtml page.

I couldn't find any information on stackoverflow if the approach of putting utility methods in an application scoped bean would be a good or a bad choice.

Why I came across this idea is the need of reusing those methods in a bean of a wider scope then a request scoped bean (like view or session scoped bean). Correct me if I'm wrong but you should always inject same or wider scoped beans i.e. you shouldn't inject request scoped bean inside a view scoped one.

I think using utility methods from application scoped bean should be beneficial (there won't be any new object creations, one object will be created and re-used across all application), but still I would like a confirmation or someone to tell me if that is a wrong approach and why is it wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As to the bean scope, if the bean doesn't have any state (i.e. the class doesn't have any mutable instance variables), then it can safely be application scoped. See also [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/) This all is regardless of the purpose of the bean (utility or not). Given that utility functions are per definition stateless, then you should definitely be using an application scoped bean. It saves the cost of instantiating on every single request.

As to having utility methods in a managed bean, in object oriented perspective this is a poor practice, because in order to access them from EL those methods cannot be `static` while they should be. You can't use them as real utility methods in other normal Java classes. Static code analyzers like Sonar will mark them all with a big red flag. This is thus an anti-pattern. The correct approach would be to keep using a true utility class (`public final class` with `private Constructor()` with solely `static` methods) and register all those `static` methods as EL functions in `your.taglib.xml` as described in [How to create a custom EL function to invoke a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function)

At least, this is what you should be doing when you intend to have a publicly reusable library such as [JSTL `fn:xxx()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/fn/tld-summary.html), [PrimeFaces `p:xxx()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/5.3/core/) or [OmniFaces `of:xxx()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/vdldoc/current/of/tld-summary.html). If you happen to use OmniFaces, then you could, instead of creating a `your.taglib.xml` file, reference the class in [`<o:importFunctions>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importFunctions). It will automatically export all `public static` methods of the given type into EL function scope.

```
<o:importFunctions type="com.example.Utils" var="u" />
...
<x:foo attr="#{u:foo(bean.property)}" />
```

If you don't use OmniFaces, and this all is for internal usage, then I can imagine that it becomes tiresome to redo all that `your.taglib.xml` registration boilerplate for every tiny utility function which suddenly pops up. I can rationalize and forgive abusing an application scoped bean for such "internal usage only" cases. Only when you start to externalize/modularize/publicize it, then you should really register them as EL functions and not expose poor practices into public.

Comment: I was aware that the utilities should be in fact static methods but I wasn't aware that I could use them as EL functions. Thanks for your detailed answer