# Use static methods in EL

Tags: jsf, el, static-methods

I'm facing a strange problem here with EL.

I just wanted to use [String.join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) in EL but it is not working.

```
#{String.join(',', myList)}
```

This is not doing anything in JSF except prevent my page to load. I know i can do this with `<ui:repeat>` but i need to use it in EL expression.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't call a static method with EL. Create a Bean with a method to call `String.join()`

```
@RequestScoped
@Named
public class StringBean {

    public String join(CharSequence delimiter, Iterable<? extends CharSequence> elements) {
        return String.join(delimiter, elements);
    }
}
```

So you can call `#{stringBean.join(',', myList)}`

Comment: I was trying to find a way to prevent this case... Thanks mate !

Comment: There's another way though. You'll find out now you have the right terms/keywords.

Comment: You mean EL 3.0 for call static methods?

Comment: @BalusC I wrote your answers about declaring EL with tag but i feel dumb i don't understand how can i'm supposed to do in my case (using String join) ....

Answer (score 2):

i found an approach to this.

register your util class as a bean in the faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>String</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.lang.String</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

I am using org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils and it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom function that exposes your static method as a function in EL. A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function).