# I can invoke static methods in EL, is this as per the spec?

Tags: jsf, static-methods, el

I am confused about the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849097/use-static-methods-in-el) regarding static method calls in JSF EL.

I have this class with a public static method in a `@Named` bean:

```
@Named
public class StaticMethods {
    private static final ILogger logger =  LogFactory.getLogger(StaticMethods.class);
    
    public static void doSomething() {
        logger.info("called static void doSomething()");   
    }
}
```

And in my JSF page I use it like this:

`#{staticMethods.doSomething()}`

And the method gets called as shown in WildFly `server.log`:

```
09:47:22,977 INFO [Lumin-WEB#default task-32] Chrome  2bfb483b-c5c1-4079-a3bf-1dd13ec4425b a.l.m.w.u.StaticMethods: called static void doSomething()
```

How does this behavior correspond to the accepted answer and also to EL specification, where it mentions that a class has to be explicitly imported before its static methods can be referenced?

Is the reason that this works in my case, because I am using `bean-discovery-mode="all"` in my `beans.xml` ?

My WildFly-23.0.2.Final is using `Mojarra 2.3.14.SP04` which implements `jboss-el-api_3.0_spec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed supported since EL version 3.0, but **only** when you use the [method expression syntax](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/4.0/jakarta-expression-language-spec-4.0#invoking-method-expressions) with the parenthesis `()` as in `#{bean.method()}`. In older EL versions you had to create a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function-to-invoke-a-static-method).

> *where it mentions that a class has to be explicitly imported before its static methods can be referenced*

That only applies to [static **fields**](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/4.0/jakarta-expression-language-spec-4.0#imports-of-packages-classes-and-static-fields), not to static methods.

> *Is the reason that this works in my case, because I am using bean-discovery-mode="all" in my beans.xml ?*

No, the bean discovery mode has no influence whatsoever on EL property resolving. It has only influcence in whether the base (the `#{bean}` part of `#{bean.method()}`) can be resolved at all.