# Why is "Infinity" generated for #{1/0} in EL with JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, el

I needed a page to throw an exception for an experiment and added

```
#{1/0}
```

to `index.xhtml`. I expected an `java.lang.ArithmeticException`  to be thrown, however the expression evaluated to the string `Infinity` on the generated page. Division by zero is not defined and `NaN` is probably a much better choice than `Infinity`, but even `NaN` is confusing because it's not intuitive in the Java programming language where division by zero is handled with an exception instead of this return value.

Running

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    int x = 1/0;
}
```

in a backing bean causes the expected `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`.

Besides an explanation why this happens, I'd be interested in a way to throw the exception because I prefer early and severe crashs of the application during development over displaying of logical (or unlogical for that reason) string.

I checked the large list of potential duplicates (`x/0 == NaN` in other languages, etc.) carefully, but there seems to be no explanation for JSF, yet. I'm not looking for a solution of any kind (there's no problem, I just found this behavior by accident), but an explanation.

I experienced this using Primefaces 6.2.

Comment: JSF uses the `double` datatype for its numeric calculations. Its behavior is consistent with what Java does with doubles and with the appropriate IEEE standard. 1/0 is positive infinity, -1/0 is negative infinity and 0/0 is undefined (NaN)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt good explanation, thank you. You can post that as an answer. There's probably no way to thrown an exception, then.

Comment: You could try adding a [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function-to-invoke-a-static-method) around this in which you check for the string 'Infinity' and throw an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained by the specification for Expression Language 3.0, Section 1.7.1:

> "Binary operator - `A` {/,div} `B`
>
> - If `A` and `B` are `null`, return `(Long)0`
> - If `A` or `B` is a `BigDecimal` or a `BigInteger`, coerce both to `BigDecimal` and return `A.divide(B, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)`
> - Otherwise, coerce both `A` and `B` to `Double` and apply operator
> - If operator results in exception, error."

In this case, `A` and `B` are integers, so they are coerced to `Double` and the division is performed using IEE 754 floating point arithmetic ... resulting in an `INF`.

> There's probably no way to thrown an exception, then.

There are ways:

- If `A` or `B` (but not both) are `null`, then the spec implies you would get an NPE.
- In the `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` cases, the `divide` method should throw an `ArithmeticException` if `B` is zero.

Reference:

- JSR-000341 Expression Language 3.0 - http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/el-3_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html