# How can I increment a date in EL

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I am working on a calendar for PrimeFaces and I want to set the minDate as one day after today (which is tomorrow) without going into the backing bean. How do I do so on the minDate in PrimeFaces?

```
 <p:calendar id="tomorrowDate"
             value="#{calendarView.tomorrowsDate}"
             mindate="#{calendarView.applicationDate} + 1"/>
```

Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why? That mean uaers can tamper with it unless you add additional server side checks. And if the page is rendered, the minDate is already set.

Comment: I have two calendars currently. One show today's date and user can select any date before the date. And another show's tomorrow's date, depending on the user's selection of today date. The minimum date for tomorrow should always be bigger than today. That is why I wanted to cater from the EL

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem, not the reason why it should be done in EL.

Comment: If it's done in the EL, the calendar will instantly block invalid dates. The invalid dates will be greyed out and unchooseable.

Comment: Isn't that great?

Comment: That is why I want to cater it from the EL

Comment: If you create a bean method mindate="#{calendarView.tomorrowDateMinDate}" that returns users' previously selected date + 1 day it should also be reflected in tomorrowDate component UI. You can add a <p:ajax .../> to the first calender that updates tomorrowDate calender on change, such that tomorrowDate always allows to only select a greater date.

Comment: I did so @Selaron. I find no way to cater it from JSF. The only way I found is to set the minDate in the backingBean and later pass it to the JSF layer. Thank you very much by the way for the help !

Comment: You could create an EL function to do this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function-to-invoke-a-static-method

Comment: Yes, I would say that is the longer workaround version. Thank you for @JasperdeVries !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can't find a possible solution for this, need to specify minDate value in bean and fetch it from JSF.

Comment: "need to specify minDate value in bean and fetch it from JSF." isn't this one considered a solution ?