# How to read value of <Environment> entry which is defined in my META-INF/context.xml

Tags: tomcat, jsf

I have META-INF/context.xml file, which looks something like below

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <Context displayName="Game Application Dev">
     <Environment 
        name="myName" 
        value="HelloWorldApp" 
        type="java.lang.String" 
        description="This is my envName"/>
    </Context>
```

By any chance is it possible to read this **myName** entry in my **.xhtml** file **without using** any bean (which does the explicit jndi lookup). 
I know this can be done with the jndi lookup, but my requirement is to achieve the same without using any beans.

Edit 1: 
My Target server : Apache Tomcat

Comment: I suppose it is the context.xml targeted to Apache Tomcat? And you can not rewrite it as `<Parameter .../>`?

Comment: @Selaron: Yes context.xml is targeted to Apache Tomcat. Yes I can rewrite or make changes in context.xml file.

Comment: Why is it this your requirement? Why without **ANY** bean? And JSF used CDI for all injection/resource etc, so look for a CDI based solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it would still be interesting to know why you cannot add a bean to your project, one chance to access `String` typed parameters from Apache Tomcat `context.xml` is the [`getInitParam(String)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getInitParameter-java.lang.String-) method from ExternalContext:

Rewrite your `<Environment .../>` element to a [`<Parameter .../>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters):

```
<Parameter
    name="myName" 
    value="HelloWorldApp" />
```

And in your `xhtml` write:

> This is a #{facesContext.externalContext.getInitParameter('myName')}!

---

Another possibility is to [create a custom EL-Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function-to-invoke-a-static-method#7080174). But if you can't create beans, this is likely not an option for you either.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `initParam['myName' ]`
The catch point here is that initParam is an implicit function and the equivalent corresponding method is defined in the ServletConfig getInitParameter(String paramName). 
The accepted answer will also work like charm, and using initParam is another way to get the work done 
I found an interesting link which explains the fundamentals very clearly.

[Servlet config](https://way2java.com/servlets/servlet-web-xml-init-param-example-using-servletconfig/)

Little background, when servlet loads, then all the context related information is also loaded. And since you want to access one such info, first you will make sure that you rewrite your  element to a :

```
<Parameter
    name="myName" 
    value="HelloWorldApp" />
```

And then access it in either two ways.

```
{facesContext.externalContext.getInitParameter('myName')}
```

Or

`initParam['myName' ]`