# How to render content as both plain text and URL encoded

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

JSF 2.x/Primefaces 7.x

Assuming I have a

```html
<p:outputLabel id="myLabel">
  Here some static text written from a colleage without java background,
  but mixed with #{myBean.name} information from java object
<p:outputLabel>
```

or `<h:outputLabel>`.

I want offer on same page a link to email
`<a href="mailto:">`
and put the content from the label field (id=myLabel) into the email.

I also found examples like
`<a href="mailto:?subject=mySubject&body=myBody">` to pre-fill the email. So myBody should be the content from id=myLabel field.

I'm looking for a solution to pull the rendered content from label as body.
I assume, the content must also be url-encoded.

Any hints?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is a  bit unclear. I think you need to further explain exactly what you want to do. You need to show us a concrete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is add the contents of your `p:outputLabel` to a variable, using `c:var`. For example:

```html
<c:set var="myVar">Some text at #{now}</c:set>
<p:outputLabel>#{myVar}</p:outputLabel>
```

This allows you to reuse `myVar` in a link. In your case you want to use it as a URL parameter. So it needs to be URL encoded indeed. To do so you can simply use a `h:outputLink` with `f:param`s, which will automatically be URL encoded:

```html
<h:outputLink value="mailto:">
  <f:param name="subject" value="#{myVar}" />
  <f:param name="body" value="#{myOtherVar}" />
  Send mail
</h:outputLink>
```

You could also create [a custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function-to-invoke-a-static-method) to do so, or, if you are using OmniFaces you can use [`of:encodeURL`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Strings):

```html
<c:set var="myVar">Some text at #{now}</c:set>
<p:outputLabel>#{myVar}</p:outputLabel>
'myVar' URL encoded: #{of:encodeURL(myVar)}
```

Comment: I like the idea. Sorry not mentioned, but in the text part I also have formatting information like ```<br/>```. When I put it to the ```c:set``` and later use it, I still have the ```<br/>```, when I use the variable in ```p:outputLabel```. Not yet found to escape this part. But I still investigate your solution.

Comment: Use `<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{myVar}"/>`, but read about XSS attacks before doing so.