# How to replace AbstractTagLibrary from Mojarra with standard Jakarta EE methods?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to move our application from an old **JSF 2.2** version to **JSF 3.0** (part of the **Jakarta EE 9 platform**). In the transition we want to replace the **Mojarra** implementation of **JSF** and want to replace it with the standard **jakarta.faces-api**. In the past we used explicit implementaions of **JSF**, **servlet** and other technologies, part of the Java EE specification. Now we want to use the standard-api approach.

I have a problem with a class that don't exist in the standard api but in the **Mojarra** implementation of **JSF**, the [AbstractTagLibrary](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/2.3/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/facelets/tag/AbstractTagLibrary.java).
We use a **Websphere-Liberty** in the newest version, so with activated **JSF** features the application useses **MyFaces**.

What i tried so far was to replace the **AbractTagLibrary** with an own implementation. Bot i got an error that **AbractTagLibrary** should be of type **org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.AbractTagLibrary**.

The **AbractTagLibrary** is used to create custom EL functions. Like in this [article](https://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/CreatingCustomELFunctions.html).

My question is, how can i replace the AbstractTagLibrary with the standard jsf-api approach? Is there a good way to approach such a problem?

Comment: Why is the application using Mojarra-specific `AbstractTagLibrary` in first place? What problem exactly did it think to solve that way? It should undoubtedly have been solved in another way from the beginning on which is not tight coupled to any API implementation.

Comment: I think it was implemented like 10 years ago and i am working on that project since a few months. I can not retrace the decisions that led to the current state. I can only guess. But i think the last few persons working on it did not knew any better.

Comment: I did some research within the project, as you suggested. And it's to create custom EL functions, pretty similar to: https://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/CreatingCustomELFunctions.html.

Comment: That's JSF 1.x minded. This is unnecessary since JSF 2.0. Replace by this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080174

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will replace it! :)

Answer (score 0):

As BalusC said in his comment, the approach is JSF 1.x minded and can be solved by a JSF 2.0 approach explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080174.